# How To Skip The 2nd Input Of n

Tags: c

I've been messing with functions recently and i wanted to transform the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n,tab[100];
    printf("Insert The Number Of Elements :\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("Give The Element N~%d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&tab[i]);
    }
    printf("The Elements Are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("Index[%d]=%d\n",i,tab[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... into a code where i can use functions to:

- Ask for the number of elements that the array is going to hold
- Show the output of the array with the elements the user entered

Here's what i got to so far but it seems like it keeps asking me for the number of elements the array will hold even though it has been already entered.
Thanks in advance to those who will help <3

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Number_Of(int a)
{
    printf("Insert The Number Of Elements :\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
int Array(int tab[])
{
    int i,n;
    n=Number_Of(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Index[%d]=%d\n",i,tab[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,tab[100];
    n=Number_Of(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Give The Element N~%d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&tab[i]);
    }
    printf("The Elements Are:\n");
    Array(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It keeps asking you for the number of elements? You call `Number_Of()` in the `main()` function and again in the `Array()` function.

Comment: Tip: If you know the number of elements, don't *assume* `100`. Also in `Number_Of()` that should be a local variable `a`, not some argument you treat as a local variable.

Comment: I tried making another function where i separated the printf and scanf statements and it still kept asking me for another input because where there is canf there must be an input before it! any ideas how to make it so i dont re input the number of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling "Number_Of" function two times that's why you prompted to enter again.
First time you called in main function.
Second time you called in Array function.
You can do like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Number_Of(int a)
{
    printf("Insert The Number Of Elements :\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
void Array(int tab[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Index[%d]=%d\n",i,tab[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,tab[100];
    n=Number_Of(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Give The Element N~%d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&tab[i]);
    }
    printf("The Elements Are:\n");
    Array(tab, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot the output is how i d like it to be i ll make sure to mark the modification and learn from it to not face this issue again ! :D